# Why react-redux re-render component if state don't change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have component that subscribe on `auth`:

```
export default function requireAuthComponent(Component, redirectTo = '/') {
  class RequireAuthComponent extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      return nextProps.auth.logged !== this.props.auth.logged;
    }

    render() {
      const { auth } = this.props;

      if (auth.logged) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }

      return <Redirect to={redirectTo} />;
    }
  }

  return connect(({ auth }) => ({ auth }))(RequireAuthComponent);
}
```

When I change store in nested components the RequireAuthComponent re-render too, but `auth` store didn't change, but If I add compare `auth` store in `componentShouldUpdate` it work fine. Why redux don't compare `auth` store yourself, In docs said that react-redux compare store and re-render component if old store and new store that passed in mapStateToProps aren't equal ?

```
import PrivatContainer from './container/PrivatContainer';
import requireAuth from '../../components/requireAuth';

export default store => ({
  path: '/privat',
  exact: true,
  component: requireAuth(PrivatContainer),
});
```

Comment: can you post how do you call `requireAuthComponent`

Comment: added description

Comment: Why are you putting react component instances in the redux store? If props.auth.logged is your single source of truth, you might want to rethink this whole implementation. Conditionally rendering the component somewhere in JSX might be a better option.